# repository webhook gives me empty json

Tags: php, webhooks

I'm trying to connect my repository to a php file, hosted in a free web server, with a webhook.

The problem is that I don't receive any data.

This is my webhook.php file.

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($data);
```

And these are request and response headers details from Github:

**Request Headers**

```
Request URL: http://<user>.<domain>.org/webhook.php
Request method: POST
content-type: application/json
Expect: 
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/8f0ea18
X-GitHub-Delivery: 45e2783a-ec35-11e8-8444-a0221ee402c8
X-GitHub-Event: push
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 841
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 19:55:35 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

The response is a `200` http status.

I've tried with others repository (Bitbucket and Gitlab) but I always receive an empty json data. In particular, with Bitbucket, I've ticked off the option `Skip certificate verification` but without any positive result.

Thanks

---

**Edit 1**

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (empty($data)) {
    echo 'empty';
} 
else {
    echo strlen($data);
}
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($data);
```

returns `empty` even if response headers' content-length is not `0`.

Comment: How did you determine that no data was received? The response headers' Content-Length show a larger size than the headers alone, which would indicate a body was sent. Check if $data contains any data, before you pass it through json_decode().

Comment: I've added a test, see Edit 1. The result of `file_get_contents` is `empty`.